# remove duplicates from array in moment js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

i have

```
let  array = [moment('2019-01-17'),moment('2019-01-19'),moment('2019-01-19'),moment('2019-01-21')];
```

i need to remove duplicates

so i written filter but it is not working correctly

```
array= array.filter((v,i) => !moment(array.indexOf(v)).isSame(moment(i)))
```

working live [plunker](https://next.plnkr.co/edit/5UoRI9PsiVAy0ZNL?open=lib%2Fapp.ts&deferRun=1) code inside index.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You were on the right track, but details were a bit off. Please try this:

```
const comparisonValues = array.map(v => v.valueOf());
array = array.filter((v,i) => comparisonValues.indexOf(v.valueOf()) == i);
```

Explanation:

- `array.filter((value, index, self) => self.indexOf(value) == index)` is an useful pattern for finding unique values in an array
- The intuition behind the pattern is to "pick only *first* instances of a value in an array"
- It only works for values that can be directly compared - indexOf uses strict equality check internally (`===`)
- `momentValue.valueOf()` will return an useful value for this comparison, namely number of milliseconds since the Unix Epoch
- Our solution uses a helper array that consists of the millisecond values from `valueOf` and in `filter`, makes comparisons using `valueOf()` of the current value in iteration

Another way, if you want to use `isSame`, could be like this:

```
array = array.filter((v, i) => {
  return array.findIndex(candidate => v.isSame(candidate)) == i
});
```

Comment: can you give guidance to to use isSame(moment function) in your answer

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the same result and **faster** with just a single [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and once you got the items grouped just get them via [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values). This would be faster than for each items searching the entire array every time. For small arrays it would not matter but for larger it would be quite noticeable.

Here is the concise version:

```js
let data = [moment('2019-01-17'), moment('2019-01-19'), moment('2019-01-19'), moment('2019-01-19'), moment('2019-01-19'), moment('2019-01-21')];

const result = data.reduce((a, c) => (a[c.format()] = c, a), {})

console.log(Object.values(result))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```

And here the detailed one:

```js
let data = [moment('2019-01-17'), moment('2019-01-19'), moment('2019-01-19'), moment('2019-01-19'), moment('2019-01-19'), moment('2019-01-21')];

const result = data.reduce((accumulator, current) => {
   accumulator[current.format()] = current
   return accumulator
}, {})

console.log(Object.values(result))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: why your code showing output wrong? like [
  "2019-01-16T18:30:00.000Z",
  "2019-01-18T18:30:00.000Z",
  "2019-01-20T18:30:00.000Z"
]

Comment: What is wrong with it? It is just string representation of moment objects.